# Pass infinite arguments from function to function in Scala

Tags: scala, arguments

I am new to Scala and recently I am facing this problem, I need to call function A with X arguments and after that it will call function B with same X parameters, but the problem is I always get "WrappedArray" and so on.

In Lua I would simply do this:

```
function processInfArgs(output,...)
    for i,v in ipairs({...}) do
         output[i]=tostring(v) --just example, stringify it
    end
end
function takeInfArgs(...)
    local out = {}
    processInfArgs(out,...)
    return out
end
local result = takeInfArgs(1,2,3.14,"four","five")
for i,v in pairs(result) do
    print(v,type(v))
end
```

And I would get this:

```
1       string
2       string
3.14    string
four    string
five    string
```

So I tried to do something like this in Scala:

```
import scala.collection.mutable

object AppMain extends App {
  def processInfParams(output: mutable.ArrayBuffer[Any],params: Any*): Unit ={
    for( param <- params ){
      output += param.toString
    }
  }
  def takeInfParams(params: Any*): mutable.ArrayBuffer[Any] ={
    val output= mutable.ArrayBuffer[Any]()
    processInfParams(output, params) //this somehow converts it to WrappedArray(...)!
    output
  }
  val out = takeInfParams("Param 1","Param 2","Param 3",4,5,6)
  for( thing <- out ){
    println(thing+"\t"+thing.getClass.getName)
  }
}
```

And I get this:

```
WrappedArray(Param 1, Param 2, Param 3, 4, 5, 6)    java.lang.String
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With this:

```
processInfParams(output, params) //this somehow converts it to WrappedArray(...)!
```

you can make params to expand as follows:

```
processInfParams(output, params:_*)
```

by using the `:_*` that followed `params`.